# Can I run a 2xAAA battery device on a 5 volt USB device without the motor burning out?

Tags: overheat

Just wondering and I don't want to waste parts if it will just burn out if I have it plugged in too long.

Comment: What does "% volt" mean? Is a "motar" really a motor?

Comment: I think the % is a shifted 5 key

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what the device is, so the answer would have to be "maybe".

Answer (score 1):

You will likely damage the device immediately. 2 x AAA batteries is equivalent to about 2.5V, USB is 5V